# Find all records that are cheaper than a specific record in a database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hello being a starter in mongo, i am struggling with this:

I have a Mongo database with the following profile:

```
[
 {'ean':123456,'group':'A','price':1},
 {'ean':123456,'group':'B','price':1.2},
 {'ean':123456,'group':'C','price':1.1},
 {'ean':1123456,'group':'A','price':1},
 {'ean':1123456,'group':'B','price':0.9},
 {'ean':1123456,'group':'C','price':1.3}
]
```

I want to identify for which `ean` from group A (so looping through distinct `ean`'s from group A), which are the other from other groups that are cheaper in terms of price.
Example: So in this case I should have a result of `{ean: 1123456,'group':'B','price':0.9}`  as if I check price from group A it's 1, I see that group B for the same `ean` has a cheaper price.

How could I achieve this?
I tried with some distinct count like:

```
collection.distinct('ean',filter={'group':'A'})
```

but that only gives me a list of `ean`'s from group A. That's a start..how do you recommend continuing?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This would help you

- `$facet` helps to categorize incoming documents. So mention you need to compare group A among others, so we categorize into separate array `getAEan` and get the `ean`. The other category is `groupAll` which has all minimum price documents. Because we sorted by price and get the first of each document.
- `$sort` helps to sort the document by price
- `$group` helps to group the documents and find the minimal price document
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array `getAEan`
- `$filter`- we have all documents in `groupAll` array. we can exclude unwanted documents which doesn't have Group A's ean.
- `$limit` to get the first document which was sorted by price
- `$replaceRoot` to make it as root

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "getAEan": [
        { $match: { group: "A" } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            ean: { $push: "$ean" }
          }
        }
      ],
      "groupAll": [
        { "$sort": { price: 1 } },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$group",
            "price": { "$first": "$price" },
            ean: { $first: "$ean" }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$getAEan" },
  {
    $project: {
      group: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$groupAll",
          "cond": { $in: [ "$$this.ean", "$getAEan.ean" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$group" },
  { "$sort": { "group.price": 1 } },
  { "$limit": 1 },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$group" } }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uSw30HcrVpw)**

Comment: Thanks a Lot ! I had to correct a bit to adapt to a pymongo query, unfortunately i have this error message: pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: $push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': '$push used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes', 'code': 146, 'codeName': 'ExceededMemoryLimit'}

Comment: i added at the last line ])   -> ],allowedDiskUse=True)     but that didn't help

Comment: How much data you get?

Comment: I have 5.2 millions records....maybe that's the explanation

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to purpose a simple approach on how to handle this using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

We'd start by matching group A's documents, then `$lookup` on the same collection and see if we have any cheaper matches that are not from the same group. This would be somewhat faster then executing multiple pipelined on the entire collection using `$facet` as suggested above.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      group: "A"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        ean: "$ean",
        price: "$price"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            group: {
              $ne: "A"
            },
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $lt: [
                    "$price",
                    "$$price"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$ean",
                    "$$ean"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "matched"
    },
    
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "matched.0": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1Vbd6tj1vWL)

Comment: Hello Tom, thank you for your answer, unfortunately executing this query in mongo shell doesn't bring up anything...i am searching what mistake i could have done

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/1Vbd6tj1vWL, tell me if something is wrong here

Comment: No that looks fine indeed ah but just noticed that ean is in fact a list of multiple elements in my source database ean:['123456','1123456',etc...], maybe that's the reason, thanks a lot for your input!   SORRY i checked myself by replacing ean into a list and it works as well so i will see where i am wrong. THANK you!

Comment: Thank you so much i restricted the query with adding some conditions in $match and now it works! Thank you so much for your help!